# C# Socket Send the string multiple times (How to remove the while(true) loop)

Tags: c#, sockets, server

I have a C# server that sends a string to an Android JAVA Client.

My Android code already receives once but I want to send that string many times per second.

```
        public void serverthread()
    {
        Thread serverthread = new Thread(server);
        serverthread.Start();
    }


    public void server()
    {

        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.5"),6000));
        estado = 1;
        socket.Listen(100);

        Socket accept = socket.Accept();

        while (true)
        {
            buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World");
            accept.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
        }
}
```

Eventually my Android Client crashes when I'm using this while(true) loop. How can i improve my implementation?

Comment: It's going to crash if it receives too much data. So you need to either not send as much, or send it slower.

Comment: This would be easier if you knew how many times you wanted to send it or had some sort of exit condition

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand what is your question completely, but if you want to prevent your client from crashing, you probably have to let it use your data. after all the client is slower than your server.
use     Thread.Sleep(time); like this

```
    while (true)
    {
        buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World");
        accept.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to clean the buffer before writing again?

Comment: Because in my android app i got like a million Hello Worlds all at once.

Comment: @Tiago o, you dont need to. see, sleep(10) make the thread sleep for 10 miliseconds. if you want to have like 1 "hello world" every seconds, change it to  Thread.Sleep(1000)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and on every `Elapsed` event do send the string to your Android client